# Creating graphic visualization in python

Tags: python, graphics

Link shows a graphic visualization taken form census website. Link for the same is shared below. I want to create graphic visualization of the same kind in my python program.

Link for the graphic visualization: 
http://www.census.gov/dataviz/visualizations/stem/stem-html/

Which kind of visualization is this? is it a piechart or any other different kind of graphic visualization.

Are there any APIs available to create such a visualization or do i need to use any web service?

Comment: It is a chord diagram.

Answer (score 2):

This tzpe of graph is called a `chord diagram`. a related question on stackoverflow can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105801/chord-diagram-in-python). Bad news is there is no answer. And, unfortunately, looking around on the internet doesn't bring much.

Comment: there is now ``mpl-chord-diagram``, see [here](https://github.com/Silmathoron/mpl_chord_diagram)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a graph that is exactly like the one listed, but matplotlib provides a huge number of options.

http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

It supports Sankey graphs as well:

http://matplotlib.org/api/sankey_api.html?highlight=sankey#module-matplotlib.sankey

Answer (score 1):

As [edouard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115377/edouard) mentioned, it is a Chord diagram. The [D3js.org](http://D3js.org) site has two examples - one static (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006 - which was listed in [the other question edouard mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105801/chord-diagram-in-python)) and one interactive (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/) which is more like the Census graphic.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially a [weighted graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_graph#Weighted_graphs_and_networks). It looks a lot like a [Sankey diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram).

There is specialized software for visualizing graphs, e.g. [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). There are several Python bindings for it.

You would have to look at the documentation if it can create this style of graph.